# Implementing FusionAuth with NextAuth (Next.js): Custom Implementation with passwordless login links

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next.js14, next-auth

I'm currently trying to implement FusionAuth with NextAuth.js, which I've managed to do with the default configuration as FusionAuth is built in. However, how users login currently is they login via an external provider. This is not done via NextAuth as it's completely self-coded, and it's not a usual provider that has support for usual / typical authentication.

As such, I've had to implement FusionAuth in a weird-ish way. Here's how I've currently implemented it:

1. The user signs in with their external account.
2. If it's non-existent in FusionAuth, create an user account for them in the database. This is done via FusionAuth's REST API.
3. Create a [passwordless login link](https://fusionauth.io/docs/apis/passwordless) for their account, again using the FusionAuth REST API, and make the redirect callback back to NextAuth's callback.

Step 3 is where I start running into problems. NextAuth by default manages by itself state, and code_challenge. This is generated every time the user attempts to press login via NextAuth, and saves cookies so when the user is redirected back, NextAuth can do some math (assumption) to check everything matches and then logs the user in. I tried looking into whether I can generate this myself, and it seems not.

I've come here to see if I'm able to implement passwordless login links and also able to log the user in. Every time I get redirected back when I try it, I run into problems where the state and code_challenge are either non-existent because it isn't done directly by NextAuth. I even went as far as attempting to fetch "/api/auth/signin/fusionauth", seeing where it redirected, and grabbing the parameters (so the code challenge and state), and shoving it on my passwordless login request. Again, this didn't work (unless I'm missing something important).

I'd really appreciate any assistance. Authentication isn't my strong point and I'd really love to learn further so any suggestions are much appreciated. Thank you.